# Accept/Decline Task Button isn't shown in notification E-Mail in Outlook 365

Tags: tasks, microsoft-outlook-365

[image]
We got some users that assign Tasks to each other. If someone gets a task assigned he normally gets an E-Mail where he can click on the Accept Button there. We got one user there the E-Mail looks like a normal E-Mail with an Outlook-Element as an addon, pulling this on the task button creates a new task.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: "We got one user there the E-Mail looks like a normal E-Mail with an Outlook-Element as an addon, pulling this on the task button creates a new task." Can you explain about that Outlook-Element? Can you show an image?

Comment: So added a picture now